# ImportingXML from different pages using google scripts

Tags: google-sheets

I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I cannot find anyone even talking about this. 
I am using the importXML function in google scripts to import data from the website www.laterooms.com, I can do this for the first page of results no problem,

```
sheet.appendRow(['=ImportXML("k16295585_london-hotels.aspx?hidfl=&k=London&d=20140911&n=1&rt-adult=2&rt-child=0&rt=2-0&currencies=GBP&distanceUnit=Miles",K1)'])
```

however the second page of results has the same URL with 6 variable characters added after a # at the end of the address, if you browse to this URL in a new window you are taken back to page 1. Similarly if you just use the URL from page 2 in the formula then you get results from page 1.
If anybody could help me determine how to call on the URL of a second page of results, or tell me where I should be asking this question (I do not think this is the right place) I would be very grateful.
This is probably a really stupid question but I am at my wits end here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need more than just `ImportXML` on the original URL for this scenario.

You need to be using something more sophisticated such as http://phantomjs.org/, https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize, etc. to programmatically navigate the site and scrape the data off of downstream pages. Tools like these, unlike ImportXML, will keep track of the cookies and sessions that sites like this use to keep track of what view state you are in.

As always, be aware of the potential legal/ethical issues with web scraping.